# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Unpickler'

Tags: python-2.7

I am running a program in the SciTE text editor and it gets stuck at the import scipy as sp statement.

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.integrate as spi
import scipy.optimize as spo
import numpy.random as nr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print "check"
#parameters to be used
rs=0.14
ra=0.0027
js=-0.033
ja=0.81
Mz=91.0
Tz=2.5 
root_s=sp.linspace(20.,140.,200)  #plotting sigma_A and sigma_S functions against   centre of mass energies from 20GeV to 140 GeV
s=(root_s)**2
.....
.....
```

and I get this error message:

```
>pythonw -u "collisions.py"
3.14159265359
1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collisions.py", line 4, in <module>
    import scipy as sp
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    from numpy import oldnumeric
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\oldnumeric\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from compat import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\oldnumeric\compat.py", line 106, in <module>
   class Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Unpickler'
>Exit code: 1
```

The odd thing is that my code works perfectly fine in the interactive qtconsole. I am new to programming, and I have not encountered such a problem elsewhere in the internet. And why is it that the values pi and 1.0 are returned even though there is no where in my code that is supposed to do that?